# Substitution method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm a 13 year old and I got to a point during my maths exercise where the negative symbol was behind the variable

Here is the question:  $3x-y=7$

Then I had to bring the $3x$ to the other side the what I was left with was $-y=7+3x$

Please can someone help me in what I did wrong

Comment: Welcome to Math. S. E.  It should be $-y=7\color{red}-3x$ after subtracting $3x$ from both sides of $3x-y=7$

Comment: Bear in mind what you're doing to both sides. If you're subtracting $3x$ from the left side to get rid of it there, then you need to subtract $3x$ from the right hand side too -- not add it!

Comment: You must do the same thing to both sides to maintain equality. Adding $-3x$ to both sides gives $3x-y-3x = -y = 7-3x$.

Comment: Mnemonic: walking over "the bridge" (the equal = sign), changes the sign. In either direction.